# How can I disable specific layouts provided by contrib modules via the layout API?

Tags: theming, 8

For example, the [Bootstrap Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_kit) module provides many layouts that I'm not using. Is it possible to only enable the specific layouts that my theme  needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind-of. With IPE you could use the patch in https://www.drupal.org/node/2849219.